# Field of fractions of $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]/\langle x^2+y^2-1\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory

This problem goes as follows:

> Prove that $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]/\langle x^2+y^2-1\rangle$ is an integral domain and that its field of fractions is isomorphic to the ring of rational functions $\mathbb{Q}(t)$.

The first part is straightforward, $x^2+y^2-1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$, and  hence a prime ideal, as $\mathbb[Q][x,y]$ is a euclidean and hence a UFD. The quotient by a prime ideal is an integral domain.

How do I do the second part? I guess, I have to set a isomorphism by making a substitution such that only one variable remains. But I don't see how $x^2+y^2-1$ is going to help me make a choice.

Comment: ${\bf Q}[x,y]$ is a UFD, but it isn't Euclidean. It's not even a PID. Think about the ideal generated by $x$ and $y$.

Comment: I have a feeling the map $x\mapsto2t/(1+t^2)$, $y\mapsto(1-t^2)/(1+t^2)$ is going to be involved somehow.

Comment: In any integral domain, prime elements generate prime ideals.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This follows from the classification of Pythagorean triples.

A little bit more detailed: The rational solutions of $x^2+y^2=1$ are parametrized $x=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$ and $y=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$. But actually the equation $\left(\frac{2t}{1+t^2}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}\right)^2=1$ holds formally in $\mathbb{Q}(t)$. Thus, there is a homomorphism $R=\mathbb{Q}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1) \to \mathbb{Q}(t)$ given by $x \mapsto \frac{2t}{1+t^2}$ and $y \mapsto \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$. Verify that it is injective, hence extends to a homomorphism $\mathrm{Quot}(R) \to \mathbb{Q}(t)$. Check that $t$ lies in the image. Hence, this homomorphism is an isomorphism.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: It *does* lead to an answer of the question when you think a little bit about it. But of course math.SE is not suited for answers which  only give the main idea ... everything should be worked out, *sigh*

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg:  To me, there is a very large gap between providing a full proof and a cryptic (to those who don't already know the link) remark about Pythagorean triples.  Doesn't your original hint basically amount to "Go look up how Pythagorean triples are parametrized and then use that?"

Comment: See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution#The_substitution

Comment: @Andreas We think too much alike. I was adding a remark on such at the same time [here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/96419/23500) See esp. the [tangent half-angle formula article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_formula)

Comment: @MathGems, yours is a better reference, I was hurrying and couldn't find it myself.

Comment: So where's the problem with a hint?!

Comment: The part I missed when I commented on the original question was how to show that $t$ is in the image. Now that I see how to do that, I don't know how I missed it!

Comment: @GerryMyerson, how to see $t$ is in the image ?

Comment: @MAS, $(1-y)/x=t$.