# Field of fractions of the ring of trigonometric functions

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm thinking about this question and no elegant idea comes to my mind. Prove that the field of fractions of $\mathbb R[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb R (t)$.

Comment: Are you sure you want $\mathbb R(t)$ and not $\mathbb R[t]$?

Comment: @AlexBecker yes. I changed the word "quotients" by "fractions" to avoid ambiguities

Comment: Ah, that's what I'd misunderstood.

Comment: use a rational parameterization of the circle

Comment: Dear user, [This answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/461548/221) is closely related.  Regards,

Comment: @MattE - Thanks! It works. I was thinking about the properties of $\mathbb (R[x])[y]/(y^2+(x^2-1))$, but in fact got lost.

Comment: I strongly believe this is a duplicate, but I can't track down the previous question at the moment.

Comment: If the field of fractions is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}(t)$, then the ring itself must embed into $\mathbb{R}(t)$. Finding an embedding into $\mathbb{R}(t)$ involves finding a pair of rational functions $x(t), y(t)$ such that $x(t)^2 + y(t)^2 = 1$. But this is precisely a rational parameterization of the circle.

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/373504/field-of-fractions-of-mathbbqx-y-langle-x2y2-1-rangle which is in turn a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96400