# For what values of $n > 1$ and a is $x^n - a$ irreducible in $\mathbb Q[x]$?

Tags: field-theory, factoring, irreducible-polynomials

$$x^n-a$$

So $n$ is any integer greater than 1, and $a$ is any integer.  $a$ being any integer is where I am running into trouble.  I have already shown and worked out a proof for this being irreducible when a is prime.  Now I am just working through examples, trying to figure out a pattern.

The exercise is asking for application of Eisenstein's Criterion only, so I am assuming that the value of n should have no effect on the irreducibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Theorem** $\ $ Suppose $\,F\,$ is a field and  $\:a\in F\:$   and $\:0 < n\in\mathbb Z.\ $ Then

$\ \ \ x^n - a\ $ is irreducible over $F \iff a \not\in F^{\large p}\,$ for all primes $\,p\mid n,\,$ and $\ a\not\in -4F^4$ when $\: 4\mid n $

For a proof see e.g.  Karpilovsky, [Topics in Field Theory, Theorem 8.1.6,](http://books.google.com/books?id=-2WR0fw9gLMC&pg=PA425&lpg=PA425) excerpted below, or see Lang's *Algebra* (Galois Theory).

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What set is F^p?  Sorry, I've never seen that notation before.

Comment: @James The $\,p$'th powers of elements of $\,F,\,$ i.e. $\,\{c^p\,:\, c\in F\}\ \ $