# $x^2+y^2-1$ irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, ideals, irreducible-polynomials

I want to show that $p(x,y)=x^2+y^2-1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$. There is already a similar problem posted:

[$\mathbb{Q}[x,y]/\langle x^2+y^2-1 \rangle$ is an integral domain, and its field of fractions is isomorphic to $\mathbb Q(t)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96400/mathbbqx-y-langle-x2y2-1-rangle-is-an-integral-domain-and-its-field)

but this question uses the irreducibility of $p(x)$ to show that it is prime and therefore an integral domain. The part of the problem I am stuck on is showing that $x^2+y^2-1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ in the first place.

I have considered taking the approach used in the above link except for backwards, but I am unsure of whether or not the converses of the theorems used still apply.

Edit: I see that this question has been marked as a duplicate, but I think I have explained how I am asking a different question than the one that was posted previously.

Comment: Try a degree argument. It's simple.

Comment: I understand that concept, but I have never worked with a multi-variable polynomial before, and am unsure of how to approach it

Comment: In the same thread there are two answers (but who has time to read them?). In [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/96419/121097) it's proved that your polynomial is irreducible.

Comment: @user26857 I have already read these answers and they are not what I was looking for- I am also unable to make comments on answers so I cannot ask for clarification on questions asked by others.

Comment: @MathStudent1324 You definitely didn't read the non-accepted answer and keep claiming that your question is different when in fact you asked for a proof that $X^2+Y^2-1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$ and this is proved there e.g. by using the Eisenstein's criterion.

Comment: @user26857 I did read the non-accepted answer- as I have expressed, I have never worked with multi-variable polynomials before and did not know how to apply any of the criterion to $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ (versus $\mathbb{Q}[x]$). Though the general structure of the proof is addressed in the other question, I did not understand how to apply this structure to a multi-variable situation, which is not discussed in the other question.

Comment: It seems to me that you got what you want, so a reopening isn't necessary. (The answer to the original thread is even better since it helps you to prove that a polynomial like $X^7+Y^2-1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$. The method used here has a limited value.)

Comment: Another proof for this question is to use the fact that if $x^2+y^2 -1$ is reducible then so does $x^2+(y+2)^2-1$. However, we have $x^2+(y+2)^2 - 1 = x^2 + 3$ mod $(y)$ and $x^2 + 3$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, then we get $x^2+y^2-1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose that polynomial is a product $f(x,y)g(x,y)$. Then $f,g$ both must be linear because $p = x^2+y^2-1$ is of largest degree $2$. Now write down what $p = fg $ means and see what $f,g$ can actually be.

Comment: So does it suffice to let $p(x,y)=(ax+by+c)(mx+ny+r)$, $p(x)=amx^2+bny^2+(an+bm)xy+(ar+mc)x+(br+nc)y+cr$, set up a system of equations (e.g. $am=1$, $bn=1$, $ar+mc=0$, $br+nc=0$, etc.), and find a contradiction?

Comment: Exactly, @mathstudent1324