# $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/\langle y^2-g(x) \rangle$ is integrally closed in its fraction field.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

> Let $g(x)=(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)$ with $a\neq b\neq c$. Then $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/\langle y^2-g(x) \rangle$ is integrally closed in its fraction field.

I manage to do with the following theorem:

> A smooth function $f$ is non-singular if and only if $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/\langle f(x,y) \rangle$ is integrally closed in its fraction field.

But how will I do without using this? Like an example has done [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96400/mathbbqx-y-langle-x2y2-1-rangle-is-an-integral-domain-and-its-field?rq=1).

Comment: What is the minimal polynomial of $\frac{u_1(x)}{v_1(x)}+g(x)^{1/2}\frac{u_2(x)}{v_2(x)}$ over $\mathbb{C}(x)$ ?

Comment: If I can show it is UFD, then it is solved. But why it is UFD?

Comment: @reuns why we want to find minimal polynomial of $\frac{u_1(x)}{v_1(x)}+g(x)^{1/2}\frac{u_2(x)}{v_2(x)}$

Comment: To find when it is integral over $\mathbb{C}[x]$, of course. And what does "monic polynomial" mean here ?