# How do I show that $y^2 - x(x-1)(x+1)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{R}[x, y]$?

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I tried writing this polynomial as a product of two polynomials $g, h$ of degree 2 and 1, respectively, and tried to arrive at a contradiction by multiplication of their coefficients. However, I arrived at an overwhelmingly large non linear condition, and gave up.

Comment: Since the $y$-degree of this polynomial is $2$, if it splits, then it must split as $(y-g(x))(y-h(x))$ for some $g, h \in \mathbb{R}[x]$. Can you finish from here?

Comment: Same as I [do here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/96419/242), using nonsquareness or Eisenstein, and UFD properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, in fact, there is a simple way to prove this result. At first, we can view the ring $\mathbb R[x,y]$ as a ring with one variable $Y$ over $\mathbb R[x]$, i.e., $\mathbb R[x, y] \cong \mathbb R[x][y]$. Note that $\mathbb R[x]$ is an integral domain and $x$ is an irreducible element in $\mathbb R[x]$. Hence, $x$ is a prime element in $\mathbb R[x]$. By
$$x \mid x(x-1)(x+1), x^2 \not \mid y^2$$
and the generalization of Eisenstein's criterion[enter link description here](http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/algebra/notes/16.pdf). Then we are done.

Comment: Wouldn't it be "x^2 \not \mid x(x-1)(x+1)"?