# Which step of using Eisenstein's Criterion goes wrong?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I've tried to prove that $x^2+y^2-1$ is irreducible in $C[x,y,z]$.

Attempt: Let $f[y](x) = x^2 + (y^2-1) \in C[y][x]$, then $f[y](x+1) = x^2 + 2x + y^2$. Let $g[x](y) = y^2 + (x^2+2x)$, then it's irreducible by Eisenstein's Criterion (x is irreducible). Hence $x^2+y^2-1$ is irreducible.

Now I know that $x^2+y^2-1$ is actually reducible, so which step of my proof goes wrong?

Comment: You have $x^2-z^2-1$ and $x^2-Z^2-1$. I suppose then $Z=z$.

Comment: Why not ask a new question instead of completely rewriting this one? Anyways, $x^2+y^2-1$ is irreducible over the complex numbers, so how do you know it's reducible?

Comment: What does *z* have to do with anything?  Your polynomial only involves $x$ and $y$.  Writing it as $x^2 + (y+1)(y-1)$, we see it is Eisenstein at $y+1$ and at $y-1$, so it is irreducible as a two-variable polynomial over the complex numbers.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/96419/242) in the linked dupe.